# How to uregister this broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver like this can anyone help me to unregister it. i dosen't know where i have registerd it so am unable to unregister it. This code I got from the net so please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends baseActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Button b1;
    Animation myAnim;
    RelativeLayout r;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);


        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangeReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
                String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";
                Snackbar snack = Snackbar
                        .make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), "Network Status : " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                View sbView = snack.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                if (networkStatus=="connected") {
                    snack.show();
                }
                else if(networkStatus=="disconnected"){
                    snack.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_container), "Network Status : " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snack.show();
                }
            }
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);





                //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        myAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //initNavigationDrawer();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splash);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: It pays to read the [Google Android Developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) This is your goto guide, use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcast receiver not unregistering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717933/broadcast-receiver-not-unregistering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the broadcast receiver you created and then use unregisterReceiver method of the LocalBroadcastManager

```
public class MainActivity extends baseActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
Button b1;
Animation myAnim;
RelativeLayout r;
ViewPager viewPager;
TextView textView;
private BroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver;
private boolean lastState;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    lastState = false;
    broadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            boolean isNetworkAvailable = intent.getBooleanExtra(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, false);
            if(lastState == isNetworkAvailable) {
                return;
            }
            lastState = isNetworkAvailable;
            String networkStatus = isNetworkAvailable ? "connected" : "disconnected";
            Snackbar snack = Snackbar
                    .make(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), "Network Status : " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            View sbView = snack.getView();
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            if (networkStatus=="connected") {
                snack.show();
            }
            else if(networkStatus=="disconnected"){
                snack.make(findViewById(R.id.activity_container), "Network Status : " + networkStatus, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snack.show();
            }
        }
    };





    //toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    myAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //initNavigationDrawer();
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);
    } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exc) {
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(NetworkStateChangeReceiver.NETWORK_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
}
```

Comment: Where did you register the receiver? and where did you unregister it ?

Comment: sorry sir, editing was not reflected. now i have redited again, you can check it now

Comment: It's Ok but you did not register the receiver in the first place, can you tell me exactly what are you trying to do so I can help you better ?

Comment: in my app it must continuously broadcast for network connection means if there is not internet connection it should show snackbar alert that no internet connection if internet gets connected it should show snackbar alert that internet is connected. this is my need

Comment: When there is a network change the snackbar comes two or three times the same alert. Someone in stack overflow told me that since I haven't unregistered this problem occurs.

Comment: In my first code there was only problem with two or three times repeatation rather than it was completely fine alert for network change

Comment: But if you unregistered the receiver you won't be able to receive any more broadcasts at all, I will edit my answer and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Ok I finished editing it, but keep in mind that I wrote it on notepad so you might find syntax errors "I hope not".

Comment: Thank you sir. it is sucessful

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public void unregisterBroadcast(){
    PackageManager pm  = this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(NetworkService.this, ConnectivityStateReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Log.e(TAG, "Broadcast: DISABLED!" );
}
```

Comment: its asking some paramemter or expression here public void unregisterBroadcast()